# How do I remove/prevent scroll bars on new 810px wide iframe page

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

I created a wordpress theme 810px wide to fit the new Page width. But I am getting scroll bars. How do I prevent or remove the scroll bars?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The FB guideline on managing scrolls bars is to use [FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/) from the JS SDK. Please understand that the theme you put together should preferably be within about 800px (our implementations have gone up til 802px and it has worked fine), but the height can grow as much and with the integration of FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow, you should see only one scrollbar - that on Facebook's own page which should cover your entire content.

Comment: I'm still learning :) And I don't understand those directions :) I did go and change my theme to 800px and even added this code I found online:

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [FB.Canvas.setSize();](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/) to remove *vertical* scroll bars. You will need to do his on document.ready, and any other time your page resizes. I advise against `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();` as it's much more efficient to only call setSize() when needed.

You will need to call FB.init() prior to setSize(). If you were to use the sample code from the top of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ then you can call setSize() where it says

```
// Additional initialization code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Add this to the div's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

First, set the height and and width (810px) of your page in the CSS added overflow: hidden then set them again in the first line of code here and replace the opening body tag with this:
(remember to replace YOURAPPID with your App Id too)

```
<body onload="FB.Canvas.setSize({width: 810, height: 910})">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOURAPPID;
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
} ());
</script>
```